# Why ASCII letter A has a Hamming Distance of 3?

Tags: hamming-code, hamming-distance

[image]
My question is what does [this construction gives a Hamming Distance a distance of 3] means? Why the Hamming Distance of ASCII letter A is 3? How do you determine the Hamming Distance is 3?

This is an excerpt from Computer Network by Andrew S. Tanenbaum page 206.

Comment: The *Hamming code* has Hamming distance 3. A particular letter doesn't have Hamming distance, since distance is a two-argument function: it gives the distance (in Hamming metric) between two binary vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *code* is a collection of binary vectors of some length $n$, known as *codewords*. The *Hamming distance* between two codewords $x,y$ is the number of positions $i$ such that $x_i \neq y_i$. The *minimum distance* of a code is the minimum Hamming distance between two different codewords.

For example, the [Hamming(7,4) code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming(7,4)) consists of 16 codewords of length 7:

```
0000000
1110000
1001100
0111100
0101010
1011010
1100110
0010110
1101001
0011001
0100101
1010101
1000011
0110011
0001111
1111111
```

You can check that any two codewords differ in either 3 or 4 positions. For example, 1010101 and 0100101 differ in the first 3 positions. Therefore the minimum distance of the code is 3.

There is absolutely no meaning for the Hamming distance of a single codeword. Hamming distance is a property of pairs of codewords.

Answer (score 0):

Tanenbaum is not saying that ASCII character "A" has a particular Hamming distance. Computerphile has [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5sskbSvha9M) that may clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

The Hamming distance between two codes is the number of times there is a different bit between them, for example between `1011` and `1111` a Hamming distance of 1.

The example that you're seeing is code correction. When you send anything through a cable there could be some errors (*change of bits `1 to 0` or `0 to 1`*). So there are some common algorithms that minimise these errors within the domain of **Information Theory**. In this example they show the binary code of the letter A before and after being received by destination, **a Hamming distance of 3 was found means that 3 bits have changed.**

I previously implemented some related functions and more details are explained on my GitHub. You can check [my git repository](https://github.com/KaramMed/Theorie-de-Codage-et-Information) if you're interested.